the data augmentation doesn't work properly
according to me, the given code should create 5700 images, which is 10 times the number of original images, instead, when I check the shape of it, it only gives 1140, which is twice the number of images. What am I missing in this code?
# Custom augmentation functions
def random_translate(image, max_translate):
    shift = np.random.uniform(-max_translate, max_translate, 3)
    translated_image = scipy.ndimage.shift(image, shift, mode='nearest')
    return translated_image

def random_rotate(image, max_angle):
    angles = np.random.uniform(-max_angle, max_angle, 3)
    rotated_image = scipy.ndimage.rotate(image, angles[0], axes=(1, 2), reshape=False)
    rotated_image = scipy.ndimage.rotate(rotated_image, angles[1], axes=(0, 2), reshape=False)
    rotated_image = scipy.ndimage.rotate(rotated_image, angles[2], axes=(0, 1), reshape=False)
    return rotated_image

def random_flip(image):
    if random.random() > 0.5:
        image = np.flip(image, axis=0)
    if random.random() > 0.5:
        image = np.flip(image, axis=1)
    if random.random() > 0.5:
        image = np.flip(image, axis=2)
    return image

def random_noise(image, noise_level=0.01):
    noise = np.random.normal(0, noise_level, image.shape)
    noisy_image = image + noise
    return noisy_image

def random_brightness(image, max_delta=0.2):
    delta = np.random.uniform(-max_delta, max_delta)
    bright_image = np.clip(image + delta, 0, 1)  # Clip to maintain valid pixel range
    return bright_image

def random_contrast(image, lower=0.8, upper=1.2):
    factor = np.random.uniform(lower, upper)
    mean = np.mean(image, axis=(0, 1, 2), keepdims=True)
    contrast_image = np.clip((image - mean) * factor + mean, 0, 1)
    return contrast_image

def random_scale(image, min_scale=0.9, max_scale=1.1):
    scale = np.random.uniform(min_scale, max_scale)
    height, width = image.shape[:2]
    scaled_image = scipy.ndimage.zoom(image, (scale, scale, 1), order=1)
    if scale < 1.0:
        pad_height = (height - scaled_image.shape[0]) // 2
        pad_width = (width - scaled_image.shape[1]) // 2
        scaled_image = np.pad(scaled_image, ((pad_height, pad_height), (pad_width, pad_width), (0, 0)), mode='constant')
    else:
        start_height = (scaled_image.shape[0] - height) // 2
        start_width = (scaled_image.shape[1] - width) // 2
        scaled_image = scaled_image[start_height:start_height + height, start_width:start_width + width]
    return scaled_image

def random_shear(image, max_shear=0.2):
    shear = np.random.uniform(-max_shear, max_shear)
    afine_tf = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.random_shear(shear)
    shear_image = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.apply_affine_transform(image, shear=afine_tf)
    return shear_image

def elastic_transform(image, alpha=1000, sigma=30):
    random_state = np.random.RandomState(None)
    shape = image.shape
    dx = scipy.ndimage.gaussian_filter((random_state.rand(*shape) * 2 - 1), sigma, mode="constant", cval=0) * alpha
    dy = scipy.ndimage.gaussian_filter((random_state.rand(*shape) * 2 - 1), sigma, mode="constant", cval=0) * alpha
    dz = scipy.ndimage.gaussian_filter((random_state.rand(*shape) * 2 - 1), sigma, mode="constant", cval=0) * alpha
    x, y, z = np.meshgrid(np.arange(shape[0]), np.arange(shape[1]), np.arange(shape[2]), indexing='ij')
    indices = np.reshape(x + dx, (-1, 1)), np.reshape(y + dy, (-1, 1)), np.reshape(z + dz, (-1, 1))
    distored_image = scipy.ndimage.map_coordinates(image, indices, order=1, mode='reflect')
    return distored_image.reshape(image.shape)


def custom_data_generator(images, labels, batch_size,
                          max_translate=10, max_angle=15, noise_level=0.01,
                          max_delta=0.2, lower_contrast=0.8, upper_contrast=1.2,
                          min_scale=0.9, max_scale=1.1, max_shear=0.2, alpha=1000, sigma=30):
    num_images = images.shape[0]
    while True:
        batch_indices = np.random.choice(num_images, batch_size)
        batch_images = []
        batch_labels = []
        for idx in batch_indices:
            image = images[idx]
            label = labels[idx]

            # Apply all augmentation functions
            image = random_translate(image, max_translate)
            image = random_rotate(image, max_angle)
            image = random_flip(image)
            image = random_noise(image, noise_level)
            image = random_brightness(image, max_delta)
            image = random_contrast(image, lower_contrast, upper_contrast)
            image = random_scale(image, min_scale, max_scale)
            image = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.random_shear(image, max_shear)
            image = elastic_transform(image, alpha, sigma)

            batch_images.append(image)
            batch_labels.append(label)

        batch_images = np.array(batch_images)
        batch_labels = np.array(batch_labels)
        yield batch_images, batch_labels


# Directory to save the images
save_dir = 'mri_augmented_images'
os.makedirs(save_dir, exist_ok=True)

for i in range(mri_resized.shape[0]):
    for j in range(mri_resized.shape[3]):  # Loop over channels
        img_array = mri_resized[i, :, :, j]
        img = Image.fromarray((img_array * 255).astype('uint8'))  # Scale to [0, 255] and convert to uint8
        img.save(os.path.join(save_dir, f'image_{i}_channel_{j}.png'))

# Using the custom data generator to augment images and retain labels
target_num_images = 5700
batch_size = 3  # Define your batch size
num_batches_needed = (target_num_images + batch_size - 1) // batch_size
data_gen = custom_data_generator(mri_resized, labels, batch_size=batch_size)

# Generate and save augmented images with labels
for batch_images, batch_labels in data_gen:  # Directly iterate over the generator
    for j, img_array in enumerate(batch_images):
        img = Image.fromarray((img_array[:, :, 0] * 255).astype('uint8'))  # Save only the first channel
        img_index = i * batch_size + j
        img.save(os.path.join(save_dir, f'aug_image_{img_index}_label_{batch_labels[j]}.png'))

print(f"Generated and saved {target_num_images} aug

mented images.")


Instead of generating fixed images in this way, why not use an existing library and generate randomly augmented images on the fly in every epoch? See Albumentations for example.

The code itself is not a complete working example. Your target_num_images and num_batches_needed don't seem to be used anywhere either.
